# i want to make http 1.1 200 response with C

Tags: c, websocket, http-headers, httpresponse

I want to build a web server so that the client can view the index.html document in the local Linux environment using http 1.1.

I don't know how to send proper html information to the client because I lack programming knowledge.

How to configure a web server to send such a response in the c language environment?

example bad Request)

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2023 11:27:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (FreeBSD)
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

example Good Request)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK     
Date: Mon, 28 Nov 2022 06:11:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (FreeBSD)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

Code

```
void send_data(int s, char * path) { //path='/index.html' 
  char buf[1024];
  char filename[256];
  char protocol[] = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n ";   
  char server[] = "Server: Linux Web Server\r\n ";  
  char cnt_len[] = "Content-length:2048\r\n\r\n";
  FILE * send_file;
  sprintf(filename, "htdocs%s", path);
  printf("[%s]\n", filename);
  send_file = fopen(filename, "rb");
  printf("%d fileopen\n", send_file);
  if (send_file == NULL) {
    send_error(s);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }
  send(s, protocol, strlen(protocol), 0);
  send(s, server, strlen(server), 0);
  send(s, cnt_len, strlen(cnt_len), 0);
  int len = 1;
  while (len != 0) {
    len = fread(buf, 1, 1024, send_file);
    send(s, buf, len, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: HTTP is application layer protocol which is usually sent in the payload of a TCP packet (transport layer). Not sure what you are doing..

Comment: With a lack of programming knowledge you should consider starting with an easier project than programming a web server. Please [edit] your question and show your (incomplete/non-working) code as a [mre] and explain what's wrong with it or what exactly you need help with.

Comment: ...and be sure that you understand the stream nature of TCP and how important it is to correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like send().

Comment: What is the purpose of the project? Is it for learning? What exactly do you want to learn? Do you need a replacement for an existing web server implementation? What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: This probably isn't your problem, but rather than artificially setting `len = 1` before your data-copying loop, you could use `do { len = fread(buf, 1, 1024, send_file); send(s, buf, len, 0); } while (len > 0);`, or (even better) `while((len = fread(buf, 1, 1024, send_file)) > 0) { send(s, buf, len, 0); }`.

Comment: You can find an example of a simple echo server here: https://mohsensy.github.io/programming/2019/09/25/echo-server-and-client-using-sockets-in-c.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless the file is actually 2048 bytes in size, then hard-coding the `Content-length` header to a value of `2048` is wrong. You need to send the file's actual size instead.

Also, you need better error handling.

Try something more like this:

```c
int send_raw(int s, const char *data, size_t size) {
  while (size > 0) {
    int sent = send(s, data, size, 0);
    if (sent < 0) {
      return -1;
    }
    data += sent;
    size -= sent;
  }
  return 0;
}

int send_str(int s, const char *data) {
  return send_raw(s, data, strlen(data));
}

void send_data(int s, const char *path) { //path='/index.html' 
  char buf[1024];
  char filename[256];
  char protocol[] = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
  char server[] = "Server: Linux Web Server\r\n";
  char cnt_len_fmt[] = "Content-Length: %ld\r\n\r\n";
  char cnt_len[48];
  FILE *send_file;

  snprintf(filename, 256, "htdocs%s", path);
  printf("[%s]\n", filename);

  send_file = fopen(filename, "rb");
  printf("%p fileopen\n", send_file);

  if (send_file == NULL) {
    send_error(s);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  if (fseek(send_file, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
    send_error(s);
    fclose(send_file);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  long file_size = ftell(send_file);
  if (file_size == -1L) {
    send_error(s);
    fclose(send_file);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  rewind(send_file);    
    
  sprintf(cnt_len, cnt_len_fmt, file_size);

  if (send_str(s, protocol) < 0) {
    fclose(send_file);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  if (send_str(s, server) < 0) {
    fclose(send_file);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  if (send_str(s, cnt_len) < 0) {
    fclose(send_file);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  size_t len;
  for(long offset = 0; offset < file_size; offset += len) {
    len = fread(buf, 1, min(file_size-offset, 1024), send_file);
    if (len < 1) {
      printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
      break;
    }
    if (send_raw(s, buf, len) < 0) {
      printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(send_file);
}
```

Otherwise, you can omit the `Content-length` header and send a `Connection: close` header instead. But you will have to actual `close()` the socket when you are done sending the file, eg:

```c
...

void send_data(int s, const char * path) { //path='/index.html' 
  char buf[1024];
  char filename[256];
  char protocol[] = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
  char server[] = "Server: Linux Web Server\r\n";
  char conn[] = "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
  FILE *send_file;

  snprintf(filename, 256, "htdocs%s", path);
  printf("[%s]\n", filename);

  send_file = fopen(filename, "rb");
  printf("%d fileopen\n", send_file);

  if (send_file == NULL) {
    send_error(s);
    close(s);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  if (send_str(s, protocol) < 0) {
    close(s);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  if (send_str(s, server) < 0) {
    close(s);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  if (send_str(s, conn) < 0) {
    close(s);
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return;
  }

  size_t len;
  while ((len = fread(buf, 1, 1024, send_file)) > 0) {
    if (send_raw(s, buf, len) < 0) {
      close(s);
      fclose(send_file);
      printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
      return;
    }
  }
  while (true);

  if (ferror(send_file) && !feof(send_file)) {
    printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
  }

  fclose(send_file);
  close(s);
}
```